# pyspark perform aggregate sum on multple columns in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a sample df input dataframe:

```
partner_id|month_id|value1 |value2|price1|price2|
1001      |  01    |10     |20    |1     |2     |
1002      |  01    |20     |30    |2     |3     |
1003      |  01    |30     |40    |3     |4     |
1004      |  02    |40     |50    |4     |5     |
1001      |  02    |50     |60    |5     |6     |
1001      |  02    |60     |70    |6     |7     |
1001      |  03    |70     |80    |7     |8     |
```

I want to do group on partner_id column and sum all the value columns. Aggregate code as show below:

```
df = df.groupBy(df.partner_id).agg(F.sum(df.value1).alias("value1"), F.sum(df.value2).alias("value2))
```

**resulted dataframe:**

```
partner_id|value1 |value2|
1002      |20     |30    |
1003      |30     |40    |
1004      |40     |50    |
1001      |190    |230   |
```

But, I need to select all the other columns of my input dataframe correspondind to group by column, what is the best way to acheive?

**Expected output Like:**

```
partner_id|month_id|value1 |value2|price1|price2|
1002      |  01    |20     |30    |2     |3     |
1003      |  01    |30     |40    |3     |4     |
1004      |  02    |40     |50    |4     |5     |
1001      |  02    |190    |230   |5     |6     |
```

Comment: are you selecting a random row of remaining columns? because same value of `partner_id` could associate with multiple `price1` for example.

Answer (score 0):

What is your selection for the `month_id`, `price1` and `price2` columns? I have choose the minimum.

```
df.groupBy('partner_id') \
  .agg(min('month_id').alias('month_id'), \
       sum('value1').alias('value1'), \
       sum('value2').alias('value2'), \
       min('price1').alias('price1'), \
       min('price2').alias('price2')) \
  .show()

+----------+--------+------+------+------+------+
|partner_id|month_id|value1|value2|price1|price2|
+----------+--------+------+------+------+------+
|      1002|       1|    20|    30|     2|     3|
|      1001|       1|   190|   230|     1|     2|
|      1003|       1|    30|    40|     3|     4|
|      1004|       2|    40|    50|     4|     5|
+----------+--------+------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends with the values - does the values changed according to the `partner_id`? If yes @lamanus anwer is correct, otherwise you can add it to the groupBy  part `df.groupBy('partner_id' ,'month_id')`.